# Dynamic Pivot On Categories with a Sub Category

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a list of email categories and I list out people and which categories they selected.

I now have a requirement where each email category could possibly have an Id assigned to it linking to a type within that category.

For example an Email category called Parent could have a column for a specific Class Id that is linked to a class table.
So I now need to list out the categories selected as well as the "sub categories".

My Table is similar to as follows

```
Name   CategoryName ClassId
Test1  Parent       23         //23 is reception class
Test1  General      Null
Test2  Parent       Null
Test3  Committee    Null
Test3  Parent       24        // 24 is year 1
```

What I want out is

```
Name  | Parent  | Parent-Reception | Parent-Year1 | Committee | General      
Test1 | 1       | 1                | 0            | 0         | 1
Test2 | 1       | 0                | 0            | 0         | 0
Test3 | 1       | 0                | 1            | 1         | 0
```

I am using the following sql to get it with just categories without the linked classes.

```
    DECLARE @colsSelect AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @colsSelect = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName)
            FROM   dbo.EmailCategory c           
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CategoryName) 
            FROM   dbo.EmailCategory c                
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        set @query = 'SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, ' + @colsSelect + ' from 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT                             
                            dbo.[User].Name,                                
                            dbo.EmailCategory.CategoryName,
                            1 as assigned
                FROM         dbo.[User]  INNER JOIN
                      dbo.EmailPreferences ON dbo.[User].ID = dbo.EmailPreferences.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.EmailCategory ON dbo.EmailPreferences.EmailCategoryID = dbo.EmailCategory.ID
                WHERE     
                    (dbo.[User].Email <> '''') AND (dbo.[User].Email IS NOT NULL)              ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(assigned)
                for CategoryName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

            execute(@query)
```

Is this even possible using this type of sql?

Comment: Why do you want `Test3` to have a `Parent` value of zero?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather easy (I guess) solution would be to create a view and use it instead of your current table.

In this view, you could flatten categories and subcategories so that you could use your current code with almost no change :

```
select 
  Name, 
  CategoryName
from emails
union
select 
  Name, 
  CategoryName +  '-' + c.SubName
from emails e
join classes c on c.id = e.ClassId
```

which should return something like (from your given sample)

```
Name    CategoryName
Test1   General
Test1   Parent
Test1   Parent-Reception
Test2   Parent
Test3   Committee
Test3   Parent
Test3   Parent-Year1
```

Now you replace the references to `EmailCategory` in your code to that new view, and you should be done.